# How can I use LaunchPad.net packages in 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, package-management, launchpad

[LaunchPad.net](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/) is a fantastic repository of packages, and one that I use often to install packages that are not included in the main repository. Thus far, I've always simply browsed to a package page (e.g. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/amd64/python-reportlab/2.5-1ubuntu1) and manually downloaded the Deb file, which kicks off the **Ubuntu Software Center** and lets me easily install the package.

It would be even cooler if I could use LaunchPad.net as a regular apt source, i.e. by doing something like this:

```
echo 'deb https://launchpad.net/ubuntu natty amd64' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Does anyone know what the correct sources line would be?

Comment: Jorge: Why remove Natty from the title? Lots of people Google for natty, and if the word is not in the title (and hence the URL), this question is less likely to rank highly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add Launchpad itself as a source but you can add specfic [PPA's sources for packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them).

For instance the Launchpad Project [Old and New Python Versions](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes) has a PPA settings block where it details the information needed to add that PPA to your software sources

[image]

By doing so, the packages listed on this page will be made available to you.

If you can figure out what DEB goes first here is a list of all the DEBs you need for python 2.5: [packages](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes/+packages) Open the 'python2.5 - 2.5.5-8~ppa2~natty3' and you get to see all the DEBs involved!

Comment: You're the man!

Comment: @Josh Glover it worked? :-D

Comment: It did indeed. :)